# java BufferedReader max lines

Tags: java

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;

int i = 0;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
    if(line.contains("Time:") == true){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    i++;
}
System.out.println(i);
in.close();
```

This code reads file in which is **6213238** lines, but it only reads **1244178**. Is there any  limits of lines that this class can read or is it with memory usage ? And how to make it work

**Edit:**

I have print last 18 lines like

```
while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            if(line.contains("Time:") == true){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            if(i > 1244160)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            i++;
        }
```

And it showed me 18 last lines from file. I have to say that its strange

**EDIT**
Problem was with file encoding when I changed **UTF-16** to **UTF-8**, I recive all lines from file

Comment: Um, 1244178 is bigger than 621323... are you sure those numbers are the right way round?

Comment: Assuming your numbers are reversed or something, perhaps not all lines contain the string "Time:"?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes there should be 6213238

Comment: @TedHopp increment is after condition so it count all lines looped in while

Comment: Have you tried reading from the same file using something else (like Scanner) to see if it's specific to BufferedReader? It wouldn't surprise me if it was a memory issue, but I don't see anything in the docs yet that will help.

Comment: @skowron-line what is size of your RAM and the average number of characters in one line in your file??

Comment: What tool are you using to count the number of lines in the file as 6213238?

Comment: @RajeshJAdvani i have open  this file in my texteditor

Comment: @skowron-line and size of your file plz ??

Comment: @skowron-line put print line outside if and then count number of line

Comment: @Harmeet It's already outside the if. My guess is that the text-editor is wrapping the lines and reporting the number. Don't see anything else wrong here.

Comment: @RajeshJAdvani System.out.println(line); outside if

Comment: @RajeshJAdvani may be you are correct only if lines are too long..

Comment: @HarmeetSingh but I dont want to print 600 000 lines on screen, variable i is outside IF condition so it counts all items looped in while

Comment: ok as per @RajeshJAdvani if text-editor is wrapping the lines and reporting the number. have you checked for that too ??

Comment: text-editor is not wraping lines, Bu if so im 100% sure that in some lines there is wort "Time:" at the last line there is line `Time:  11 seconds` so I checked `"Time:  11 seconds".contains("Time:")` and it was true